# How to make a click on button in PHP HTMLDOMParser?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have this URL 'http://www.clarin.com/' and i need to get one specific 'div' from him, but this div is in parent div that it has an specific class when the page is loaded, but when you click on this parent div, the name of the class changes from *nav-btn nav-noticias visto had-ad* to *nav-btn nav-noticias visto had-ad over*

[image]

How can i get this dom with a previous clic perform?

[image]

Comment: The solution that i found out was scan all entire newspaper's home with pure HTML instead of try to read only this specific section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't do it with pure php. Because this DOM change happens inside a browser DOM engine, and PHP works with inital DOM HTML.

But you can do it with, for example, PhantomJS + PHP.
Good example/tool for working with phantom is Codeception.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Finally, i resolved in another way!

Comment: It could be a good carma if you'll edit your answer and tell us about your workaround